# Refresh button hangs up GWT application

Tags: gwt, refresh

I have a problem with my GWT (2.5.0) app: on some (not all) pages when user hits "refresh" or F5 button, my app stops responding and only shows loading wheel. For example, on page `http://127.0.0.1:8888/portal/index.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997#categories` refresh works fine, but on `http://127.0.0.1:8888/portal/index.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997#dataset/1474` it doesn't, and I should manually go to `127.0.0.1:8888/portal/index.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997` to make it up again. 
When my up starts first time i have this message:

```
    Loading module: portal
  Top URL: http://127.0.0.1:8888/portal/index.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
  User agent: FF
  Remote host: localhost:33702
  Tab key: 0x942f6ad0
  Session key: *u'04>->84mG9\V\
DEBUG: Validating units:
  INFO: Ignored 4 units with compilation errors in first pass.
Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
INFO: Module portal has been loaded
```

When I hit refresh, I got this:

```
Loading module: portal
  Top URL: http://127.0.0.1:8888/portal/index.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997#dataset/247
  User agent: FF
  Remote host: localhost:33727
  Tab key: 0x942f6ad0
  Session key: j[!{tfNQto8{^&>D
DEBUG: Validating units:
  INFO: Ignored 4 units with compilation errors in first pass.
Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
DEBUG: Rebinding com.example.portal.ui.client.dataset.rpc.VDatasetDGService
  DEBUG: Adding '46' new generated units
    DEBUG: Validating units:
      TRACE: Errors in 'generated://C89FA10FB0221276522030F263FADCFA/com/example/core/application/api/DashboardAnnotationDto_FieldSerializer.java'
      TRACE: Errors in 'generated://444002CF23E85026C65248F49EB99E1E/com/example/core/application/api/DashboardColumnDto_FieldSerializer.java'
      TRACE: Errors in 'generated://7DEC0CE328D95C92EEBFD44D58F865CD/com/example/core/application/api/DashboardDto_FieldSerializer.java'
      TRACE: Errors in 'generated://5A1445C62C01E373F4894D65809B536E/com/example/core/application/api/SavedViewDto_FieldSerializer.java'
      TRACE: Errors in 'generated://B1CFA3457166E1C34069A9879469FFA2/com/example/portal/ui/client/common/rpc/AccessDeniedUiException_FieldSerializer.java'
      INFO: Ignored 5 units with compilation errors in first pass.
Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
        INFO: See snapshot: /tmp/com.example.core.application.api.DashboardAnnotationDto_FieldSerializer2049573901487473293.java
        INFO: See snapshot: /tmp/com.example.core.application.api.DashboardColumnDto_FieldSerializer2257704401750789459.java
        INFO: See snapshot: /tmp/com.example.core.application.api.DashboardDto_FieldSerializer256293197012885556.java
        INFO: See snapshot: /tmp/com.example.core.application.api.SavedViewDto_FieldSerializer8667778097358587561.java
        INFO: See snapshot: /tmp/com.example.portal.ui.client.common.rpc.AccessDeniedUiException_FieldSerializer4641234980664694792.java
INFO: Module portal has been loaded
```

If this information is not enough, ask for more, please.

Here is the more detailed part of log when refresh fails:

```
com.example.portal.ui.client.dataset.rpc.VDatasetDGService_Proxy
  DEBUG: Adding '46' new generated units
    TRACE: Compiling...
    TRACE: Invalid Unit: com.example.core.application.api.SavedViewDto_FieldSerializer
    TRACE: Invalid Unit: com.example.core.application.api.DashboardColumnDto_FieldSerializer
    TRACE: Invalid Unit: com.example.core.application.api.DashboardAnnotationDto_FieldSerializer
    TRACE: Invalid Unit: com.example.core.application.api.DashboardDto_FieldSerializer
    TRACE: Invalid Unit: com.example.portal.ui.client.common.rpc.AccessDeniedUiException_FieldSerializer
    TRACE: Invalid units found: 5
    TRACE: Compiling...
      TRACE: Compilation completed in 0,00 seconds
      TRACE: Compilation completed in 0,43 seconds
    TRACE: Added 5 units to cache since last cleanup.
    DEBUG: Validating units:
    TRACE: Removing invalidated units
      TRACE:    s in 'generated://C89FA10FB0221276522030F263FADCFA/com/example/core/application/api/DashboardAnnotationDto_FieldSerializer.java'
      TRACE: Errors in 'generated://444002CF23E85026C65248F49EB99E1E/com/example/core/application/api/DashboardColumnDto_FieldSerializer.java'
      TRACE: Errors in 'generated://7DEC0CE328D95C92EEBFD44D58F865CD/com/example/core/application/api/DashboardDto_FieldSerializer.java'
      TRACE: Errors in 'generated://5A1445C62C01E373F4894D65809B536E/com/example/core/application/api/SavedViewDto_FieldSerializer.java'
      TRACE: Errors in 'generated://B1CFA3457166E1C34069A9879469FFA2/com/example/portal/ui/client/common/rpc/AccessDeniedUiException_FieldSerializer.java'
  DEBUG: Relinking module 'portal'
        TRACE: Line 32: com.example.core.application.api.BaseLongIdentifiedDto_FieldSerializer cannot be resolved to a type
        TRACE: Line 43: com.example.core.application.api.BaseLongIdentifiedDto_FieldSerializer cannot be resolved to a type
        INFO: See snapshot: /tmp/com.example.core.application.api.DashboardAnnotationDto_FieldSerializer5862698034462806589.java
        TRACE: Line 44: com.example.core.application.api.BaseLongIdentifiedDto_FieldSerializer cannot be resolved to a type
        TRACE: Line 58: com.example.core.application.api.BaseLongIdentifiedDto_FieldSerializer cannot be resolved to a type
        INFO: See snapshot: /tmp/com.example.core.application.api.DashboardColumnDto_FieldSerializer6902331775752414472.java
        TRACE: Line 52: com.example.core.application.api.BaseLongIdentifiedDto_FieldSerializer cannot be resolved to a type
        TRACE: Line 65: com.example.core.application.api.BaseLongIdentifiedDto_FieldSerializer cannot be resolved to a type
        INFO: See snapshot: /tmp/com.example.core.application.api.DashboardDto_FieldSerializer5870139301570285930.java
        TRACE: Line 183: com.example.core.application.api.BaseLongIdentifiedDto_FieldSerializer cannot be resolved to a type
        TRACE: Line 210: com.example.core.application.api.BaseLongIdentifiedDto_FieldSerializer cannot be resolved to a type
        INFO: See snapshot: /tmp/com.example.core.application.api.SavedViewDto_FieldSerializer1128689625908711248.java
        TRACE: Line 12: com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.lang.Exception_FieldSerializer cannot be resolved to a type
        TRACE: Line 21: com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.lang.Exception_FieldSerializer cannot be resolved to a type
        INFO: See snapshot: /tmp/com.example.portal.ui.client.common.rpc.AccessDeniedUiException_FieldSerializer717502603474217145.java
```

and here is when it works:

```
com.example.portal.ui.client.dataset.rpc.VDatasetDGService_Proxy
  DEBUG: Adding '46' new generated units
  DEBUG: Relinking module 'portal'
    TRACE: Compiling...
    TRACE: Added 0 units to cache since last cleanup.
    TRACE: Removing invalidated units
```

Comment: Check if your query is simlar to - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202964/serializationpolicy-error-when-performing-rpc-from-within-gwt-application

Comment: Did you make any progress on this?

Comment: I got the same issue. Restarting of dev mode fixes the problem... temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you should drill down to your RPC service and models associated with VDatasetDGService and fix them.

Set GWT Compiler options -logLevel TRACE and then try compile with strict flag true. They might show you more information related to VDatasetDGService errors.

Comment: Ok, I've updated my post and added detailed log. Still it doesn't make any sense for me.