# Using HashSet in Serializable leads to DenseImmutableTable cannot access its superclass

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc

When I add the HashSet field in my SerializableWhiteList (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4235302/1240328), I got the exception during any RPC call. I don't need it already, but I would like to know why this happens.

```
Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.google.common.collect.DenseImmutableTable cannot access its superclass com.google.common.collect.RegularImmutableTable
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1183)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1728)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1611)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.SerializationPolicyLoader.loadFromStream(SerializationPolicyLoader.java:204)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.loadSerializationPolicy(RemoteServiceServlet.java:95)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.doGetSerializationPolicy(RemoteServiceServlet.java:420)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.getSerializationPolicy(RemoteServiceServlet.java:234)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.prepareToRead(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:505)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.decodeRequest(RPC.java:240)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:296)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:373)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.persist.PersistFilter.doFilter(PersistFilter.java:89)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:163)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:118)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

shared/ ... /SerializableWhiteList.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class SerializableWhiteList implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public NullBool nullBool;
    public HashSet hashSet; // Without this line, RPC works.
}
```

client/RPC.java

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("rpc")
public interface RPC extends RemoteService {
    // some other methods

    SerializableWhiteList junk(SerializableWhiteList l);
}
```

client/RPCAsync.java

```
public interface RPCAsync {
    // some other methods

    void junk(SerializableWhiteList l, AsyncCallback<SerializableWhiteList> async);
}
```

Comment: Does `SerializableWhiteList` have a zero argument constructor? Also, which of your classes uses `DenseImmutableTable`?

Comment: @Baz Yes, I listed full `SerializableWhiteList` code here, except for the package declaration.
It is funny, I never even hear about `DenseImmutableTable` before. The only thing leads to this error is the (never used) HashSet field.

Comment: So what's `NullBool`?

Comment: @Baz `NullBool` is my own class for saving type of the `null` boleans in serialized Map<Object>. It does not related to the problem.

Comment: Is it serializable, does it have a null argument constructor and does it use anything from Google's Guava library?

Comment: @Baz Yes, yes, no (it has just a Boolean field inside). But, in general, the app uses Guava and inherits `com.google.common.base.Base` and `com.google.common.collect.Collect` modules. At least, I use the `Function<F, T>` interface from Guava on client.

Comment: Are you using Guava on the client side or in shared objects? If so, are you using a GWT implementation of Guava (if one exists)?

Comment: Ah, I see Guava actually does work with GWT. My bad. Then Im out of ideas, sorry.